# How to temporarily spoof ᴍᴀᴄ address without root?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, tablet, 8.1-oreo, mac-address

There are many claims that it’s possible to change Wi‑Fi ᴍᴀᴄ address temporarily, but each time there’s a permission error when running one of the commands.

How to temporarily change ᴍᴀᴄ address without rooting the phone ?

Comment: Afraid that's not possible. All solutions I've ever heard of require root access. Can you link to some of those "many claims"? And were those just "empty claims" or are some of them backed?

Comment: @Izzy https://www.techpluto.com/how-to-temporarily-change-android-mac-address-without-rooting/ https://geekeasier.com/change-mac-address-in-android-devices-without-root/4792/ https://itechhacks.com/how-to-change-mac-address-android/ https://techprobsolution.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-change-android-mac-address_6.html. Typically, the explanation is the change is lost after reboot and that rooting is only required for making the change automatic on boot.

Comment: Well, the first article includes a description of how to do it. But I never saw any of the "apps available" it speaks of (all apps to change the MAC I saw explicitly mention requiring root). The other articles also describe the steps. As those articles are dated 2016 and before, my guess would be that Android 8 (and maybe even 7) made that impossible.

Comment: @Izzy I would even say I never got those steps working on kitkat. Those links are just claims.

Comment: if you were in a Mediatek Device, you could spoof mac address using MTK Engineering mode without root. Dialing *#*#*3646633#*#\* on the dialpad will take you to Engineermode. From there, naviagting to wifi and then changing the Wifi mac address is easy. I remember there was an app on Google Play named Samsung engineer mode or something like that, but that was quite a while back. Don't know if the app is still functional

Answer (score 1):

MAC address is always spoofed temporarily since it's a read-only number burned-in hardware and a part of it uniquely identifies the manufacturer. However many network interfaces allow setting a spoofed address. In order to make the change permanent the overriding process has to be repeated on every boot.

Secondly, configuring network interfaces requires at least Linux capability `NET_ADMIN` if not whole root. So, as you have observed, it's not possible to change MAC address or IP address or do other similar network configurations without the said capability or complete root access.

Answer (score 0):

You need root to execute kernel commands to set non-default hardware addresses.

The MAC address can be spoofed with root, because you can force the kernel to mis-identify a network card.

Comment: I said without rooting.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 10 and above randomized MAC address feature is available in Wifi settings of Settings app.

I have a Note 20 with Android 12 and this is how to randomize MAC address for a specific Wifi:

- Go to **Settings**
- Press on **Connections**
- Long press on **Wifi**
- Press the **Gear** on the selected Wifi Network
- Press on **View More**
- Scroll Up
- Press **MAC address type**
- Press **Randomised MAC**

Comment: And what about below 10?

Comment: @user2284570 - 4 years later, it is expected that you probably do not need an answer now.  Instead this is an updated answer for newer technologies.  Otherwise this question has no value to future visitors. Others answer address it for <10.  You may not like them, but they are what they are.